# How to locate the cell coordinates of a spreadsheet based on the value

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to locate the cell coordinates of a spreadsheet based on the **value** of the cell... So, I "put in" the value 'abcd', and the function would return the coordinates of the cell that contains that value. Ideally an array of all the "matches". Is this possible with Phpspreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out - I can use Defined Names / Named Ranges in Phpspreadsheet and "target" cells with a specific Name.